# Fix Hadoop Streaming

Tags: hadoop

I have a problem about command

```
C:\hadoop-3.3.0\Lab2>hadoop jar "C:/hadoop-3.3.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.3.0.jar" ^ 
-file mapper.py -mapper mapper.py ^ 
-file reducer.py -reducer reducer.py ^ 
-input /user/Win10/data/Cau1.txt ^ 
-output /user/Win10/data/Cau1-output.txt
```

This is command reply

```
2023-07-02 20:43:22,867 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
File: file:/C:/hadoop-3.3.0/Lab2/mapper.py is not readable.
Try -help for more information
Streaming Command Failed!
```

Hope everyone can help me fix! I use Windows

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-files` parameter not `- file`

You can check [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html) link